# Order of execution of sub reports(linked and non linked) and main report in Crystal

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I am new to crystal and want to understand the basics of subreports.Is it that main report is always executed before subreport?What if the subreport is placed in report/group header?If there are multiple subreports which are either linked or not linked to main report, what would be the order of execution in that case?Does it depend on positioning of report?

I have read many articles and got mixed responses. Please help me in understanding these concepts

Comment: In general, I understand that everything is "executed" in the order that is "printed". Summarized fields break this rule (more or less). It may not be the real way it works, but this simple mindset works for me.

Comment: (All this from personal experience.) There are few passes over entire report. First, parameters are queried/assigned and formulas, which do not depend on data (`beforereadingrecords`), are evaluated. Second, main report data is read and processed, including calculation of formulas, not depending on groups (or not marked `whileprintingrecords`), grouping and calculating group aggregates. Third, real layout is processed in order of appearance, grouped fromulas and group suppression and normal subreports and running totals are calculated. Linked subreports are executed while opened.

Answer (score 0):

Subreports are last to get processed in each section.

The key implication is that if you intend to pass a value from a subreport to the main report via a shared variable, you can't expect a formula in the same section to obtain that value. You must pass the value to a formula in a section below.